# Can I put text directly in <div>...</div>? Or do I need to wrap it in <p>...</p> first?

Tags: html, text, tags

This question sounds pretty stupid but what is the practice regarding my question. Should I always do this:

```
<div>
 Text goes here. Lots of text.
</div>
```

Or should I always wrap text in a `<p>` tag?

```
<div>
 <p>Text goes here. Lots of text.</p>
</div>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you *can* put it directly in the div. You *should* do whatever is hierarchically correct and semantically appropriate for whatever you are trying to do. That may mean you need a p tag, or it may not.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I knew how to figure out what would be hierarchically correct... I'd appreciate advice on that.

Comment: @bodacydo you might start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document. It's a useful overview of how this all works in an HTML5 world. Good luck!