# How to align copyright footer center when application is viewed on mobile or portable devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having copyrightinformation in footer but it is left aligned when i view on portable devices, but its center aligned in normal laptop screens, is there a way to make it center aligned on all devices

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
        © 2018 Copyright:  Virginia System of Care - VASOC
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
```

Is there anything to do with below code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

Comment: *Is there anything to do with below code* This question may be not helpfull, but  did you tried anything to figure it out?

Comment: How wide is the <div> element? If it's 100% then you should be able to center-align the text with a text-align:center css rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do keep in mind that is not a good practice to throw text in non text tags..

```
footer{
width:100%;
}
.footer-copyright{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Using a `<div>` for text is perfectly okay ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32803391/1813169)).

Comment: @MTCoster browser does not cares, because it simply parses it, but in html and seo standards it is not allowed, above i stated that it simply is not a good practice

Comment: The HTML5 standard ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)) simply says “*Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable.*”. While I agree its use is never encouraged at all, there is no mention of its valid children when it is used: “*It can be used [...] to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements*”.

Comment: As for SEO, there are no “standards” per se, but the use of `<footer>` would appear to be far more important than whether `<div>` appears at all ([ref](https://www.inboundnow.com/html5-semantic-elements-mean-seo/)).

Comment: [w3.org - div element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-div-element.html) and [MDN - div element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) under permitted content - allows [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#flow-content) which right at the end states text - not sure why you think it is not valid html as any html validator will not show any errors if you place text in a div

Comment: @MTCoster , Pete posted some reliable sources, it would be great for you to take a look at them

Comment: @Pete i'm clearly stating what it is not a good practice, obviously nothing happens, but as is stated https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-div-element.html - Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of the div element instead of more appropriate elements leads to poor accessibility for readers and poor maintainability for authors.

Comment: That is only for accessibility reasons - that has nothing to do with validity of html or seo - I have never been penalised on seo for putting text directly in a div - the only bad point is it may be semantically incorrect - which is completely different to what you are describing.  I don't see how a difference in tag leads to poor maintinability either

Comment: @Pete different html markup tags help your page to be contextualized by search engines better, about the maintainability you should address your suggestion to www.w3.org since it is not something that i have personally stated

Answer (score 0):

If you want a relative block:

```
.footer-copyright{position: relative; left: auto; right: auto; margin: 0 auto;}
```

If you want absolute block:

```
.footer-copyright{position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Or just set

```
.footer-copyright{width:100%; max-width: 100%; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: use this for footer tag or simply delete it and leave only footer-copyright div